# What are the different assignment operators in PHP, how do they differ

Tags: php, syntax, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I have seen references to `=` (of course) but also `.=` and `^=`.  What are those two for?  Are there others?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: And this valuable addition in the comments: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#40084

Comment: Thanks Pekka - that second comment answers the question.  In my defense, I ran a search on SO, but I don't think the search engine takes the `.=` symbol into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^=` is a [bitwise operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and `.=` is a [string operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Both are assignment operators, as they set the value of a variable after evaluating.

The former sets the value of the variable to a XOR of the expression. The latter concats the expression onto the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the binary operators (e.g. +, -, *, /) can be used in conjunction with = as shorthand for assigning values. Essentially, x += 4 is equivalent to x = x + 4.